# Get content in javascript and get results in PHP

Tags: javascript

I have this input:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="rekord" id="rekord" value="21" />
```

I have this code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
               var foo = document.getElementById('rekord').value;
              </script>
```

Now I need to have this 21 in PHP. 
How to do that?

Comment: You just want the value passed to php for output?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="">
  <input 
    type="hidden"
    name="rekord"
    id="rekord"
    value="21"
    onchange="this.form.submit()" />
</form>
```

If this doesn't work, you could use the JavaScript, which changes this input-field, to also send this form. You need an id for the form:

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="rekordForm">
```

then you can add to your JS sth like:

```
document.getElementById("rekordForm").submit();
```